# How to explore apk paths for a shared user?

Tags: java, android, api, apk

I have an APK which provides an application with id xxx. I observed
that the APK is downloaded into:

```
   /data/app/xxx-1.apk
```

If I download a new version the APK is downloaded into:

```
   /data/app/xxx-2.apk
```

And so on, incrementing the integer. Now this APK belongs to a shared
user yyy. This is noted in the AndroidManifest.xml and the installer
will automatically create the user when the first APK is installed.

How can I detect all the download paths of the APKs belonging to that
shared user yyy, that are currently installed? Is there some Android
Java API to do that? What Android version is required?

Bye

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine:

```
    try {
        PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
        String[] names = pm.getPackagesForUid(android.os.Process.myUid());
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            String name = names[i];
            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(name, 0);
            System.err.println(pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException x) {
        throw new RuntimeException(x);
    }
```